# Adding xml attribute in spring rest xml response

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc

How to add inner attribute to spring REST webservice response?

Sample xml returned by my webservice:

```
<books>
<bookId>5</bookId>
<bookName>testBook</bookName>
</books>
```

I want to use book id as xml attribute for bookName:

```
<books>
<bookName id="5">testBook</bookName>
</books>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Based on how your java types are defined you can either annotate your classes with `@XmlAttribute` or may need to write your custom [XmlAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html)